# PHP: set all values in an array to something

Tags: php, arrays

Hi want to ask if there is a way to do this without foreach ($array as $k=>$v). I know it will work but I'm looking for a more elegant way if you know.
So my array was like:

```
1 = 231
2 = 432
3 = 324
```

I flipped it and it became: `231 => 1, 432 =>2, 324 => 3`. Now what I need to do is to set all values to `'1'`

Comment: You want to refrain from using foreach to which end? Prevent the loss of the current index in your array, or just not to have to type the whole foreach structure manually?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use [`array_fill_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php):

```
$array = array(
    1 => 231,
    2 => 432,
    3 => 324
);

$array = array_flip($array);

$array = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), 1);
```

Comment: @acme: I need more coffee... :-P

Comment: Always blame it on the coffee. :P +1

Comment: What about `array_fill_keys($array, 1);` only? you don't really need to call array_flip, then array_keys :)

Answer (score 21):

[array_fill_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) should be what you need:

```
$keys = array_keys($yourArray);
$filled = array_fill_keys($keys, 1);
```

Answer (score 12):

For **PHP >5.3** you can use *anonymous functions.*

`array_walk($array,function(&$value){$value=1;});`

Note: value is passed by reference.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for this function: [array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

From the above link:

> "Fills an array with num entries of the value of the value parameter, keys starting at the start_index parameter."

Although if your indices are not numerical and/or are not enumerable (say, from 231 to 324 inclusive), then you may be better off with, as Rocket says, [array_fill_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) or your regular foreach.

Comment: He probably wants `array_fill_keys` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I got at this post with the same question but I ended up getting another aproach.

Why using array_flip + array_keys instead of simply use array_values?

```
$array = array(
    1 => 231,
    2 => 432,
    3 => 324
);

$array = array_fill_keys(array_values($array), 1);
```

Comment: The first answer is using array_flip + array_keys. My answer uses array_values, not the same answer.

Comment: `array_values()` is a needless/useless function call.

Answer (score 2):

Any method that you call, such as array_map or fill_keys would still be using a loop to iterate over the array. It seems like you would want something such as array_map, which  [can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

If you consider that to be more elegant, to each his own:)

Answer (score 2):

```
array_replace(array_flip($columns), array_fill_keys($columns, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in 1 line and creating the array is costly(e.g. It requires a query to db).

PHP 7.4 and above:

```
$array = array_map(fn() => 1, array_flip($array))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to flip the keys/values and reset all the values to the same thing (1), you can do it in one simple operation:

```
$array = array_fill_keys($array, 1);
```

---

Your array

```
$array = [
    1 => 231
    2 => 432
    3 => 324
];
```

Becomes

```
$array = [
    231 => 1
    432 => 1
    324 => 1
];
```